# What could be the reason for app.css overriding external styles. How can we prevent it from happening

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, styleclass

I have a external CSS stored in static resource. I am referencing style class from that CSS in many places( lightning components and visual force pages). After winter 18 update,few of my styles especially color and background colour of thead tag is getting overriding with styles from app.css.

I am applying same CSS  for both vf page and  lightning  component. But this is happening only in lightning components, vf page styles are not getting overrided. How to prevent this from happening and wat could be the reason

Comment: DOM tree is different in Lightning vs VF so either your selector is not valid or is not as selective as the one in app.css. Not sure this is a salesforce question, seems more like a pure CSS question without more specific details its hard to say

Comment: Sounds like the changes Salesforce communicated in this blog: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/08/winter-coming-lightning.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with my custom Lightning component on the Napili template, after the Winter'18 release(around Sep 10th), where I had the background-color attribute on the `<thead>` tag. Only fix I could make was: Having the CSS attribute in each of the `<td>` tags(Child elements). This fixed my issue.

As this is not a good practice, I have contacted Salesforce support(as `<thead>`'s CSS attributes used to function well prior to Winter' 18 release). This is what they mentioned to me:

> Modifying the background-color for this particular part of the DOM will be added in a future release. It seems to be affected by some of the CSS attributes that are being overwritten on the parent element. Thus the only workaround at this time: Adding the CSS attributes to the child elements rather than parent.

Answer (score 0):

In this scope can help you.

Let suppose you have a rule in your static resource like:

```
thead th{
   font-weight: bold;
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            Heading <!-- Your css will apply on this content only if there is no rule for this element in the salesforce css. -->
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

This can be overridden by salesforce CSS so to prevent this wrap your CSS in a scope and then wrap your elements in a wrapper and wrapper is having the top **selector/scope** selector you used in your CSS.

Let me clarify with an example:

**Old/Current** structure in static resource:

```
thead th{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

**After adding the scope/wrapper** your CSS and HTML becomes this:

```
.myScope thead th{
   font-weight: bold !important; /* here "!importatnt" is required if added with the salesforce CSS rules else you can leave it. */
}


 <table class="myScope">
    <thead>
        <th>
            Heading <!-- Your css will apply on this content only if there is no rule for this element in the salesforce css. -->
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

*To add scope to your CSS rules you can use online tools like* [SASS Compiler](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Existing structure is scoped one only but still I am facing this issue

Comment: Can you share the code structure(CSS and HTML) you are using?

Comment: stage thead {
 color:white;
Background-color: blue;
Width:5px;
}

Comment: < table class=" slds-table slds-max-medium-table-stacked slds-no-row--hover stage">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Filename </th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>

Comment: Here the CSS rule must be `.state thead{ /* styles */ }` did you forgot to post here or you forgot to add in the code as well?

Comment: Actually I missed dot while posting

Comment: @Bhuvnisha Would be really helpful if you posted your CSS and any other relevant HTML where the issue is happening with your components. Without that, it's mostly supposition. Base handling of Lightning CSS classes on the platform has changed, esp as applies to background colors of components.